# Simple file upload with php and ExtJs not working

Tags: php, file-upload, extjs, extjs4

I need the simplest solution for uploading file from Ext application with php. I'm a total php newbie, so I don't get the errors I'm recieving and can only guess what's causing them. On the frontend side I have a simple form :

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    width: 300,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    frame: false,
    title: 'File Upload Form',
    bodyPadding: '10 10 0',

    defaults: {
        anchor: '100%',
        allowBlank: false,
        msgTarget: 'side',
        labelWidth: 50
    },

    items: [{
        xtype: 'filefield',
        id: 'form-file',
        emptyText: 'Select mpp file',
        fieldLabel: 'File',
        name: 'mpp-file',
        buttonText: '',
        buttonConfig: {
            iconCls: 'upload-icon'
        }
    }],
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Upload',
        handler: function(){
            var form = this.up('form').getForm();
            if(form.isValid()){
                form.submit({
                    url: 'msp-load.php',
                    waitMsg: 'Loading data...',
                    success: function(fp, o) {
                        msg('Success', 'Data from .mpp file loaded ');
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }]
})
```

The msp-upload.php looks as follows :

```
<?
if(isset($_FILES)){
    $file_tmp  = $_FILES['mpp-file']['tmp_name'];
    $file_name = $_FILES['mpp-file']['name'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['mpp-file']['size'];

    //echo ($file_tmp.", ".$file_name.", ".$file_size);

    if(is_uploaded_file($file_tmp)) {
        if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "tmp/$file_name")){
            echo '{success: true}';
        } else {
            echo '{success: false}';
        }    
    }  else{
        echo '{success: false}';
    }
}
?>
```

After clicking 'Upload' I get :

`uncaught exception: Ext.JSON.decode(): 
You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String: 
<br> <b>Warning</b>: move_uploaded_file(tmp/MSP1.mpp) [<a href="function.move-uploaded-file">function.move-uploaded-file</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>/Library/WebServer/Documents/examples/MSProject_import/msp-load.php</b> on line <b>10</b><br> 
<br> <b>Warning</b>: move_uploaded_file() [<a href="function.move-uploaded-file">function.move-uploaded-file</a>]: Unable to move '/private/var/tmp/phpJVDktB' to 'tmp/MSP1.mpp' in <b>/Library/WebServer/Documents/examples/MSProject_import/msp-load.php</b> on line <b>10</b><br> {success: false}`

Where does this : 'No such file...' error come from? It can't find the uploaded file, or something else? My server user has admin privileges so it's not about permissions.

I'm using built-in OSX 10.7 server with PHP 5.3.6 . No errors in the error.log .

Comment: Does folder `tmp` exist?

Comment: yes it does, osx is a unix after all :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned above there are two possible problems.

1. Path Error(basically path which you are giving to upload is not valid)
2. Or the wrong permission are given. (CHMOD 777)

Answer (score 1):

You have error message from your msp-upload.php : Unable to move '/private/var/tmp/phpJVDktB' to 'tmp/MSP1.mpp' 
You have to set full destination path with write access

```
    if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, dirname(__FILE__)."/tmp/$file_name")){
        echo '{success: true}';
    } else {
        echo '{success: false}';
    }
```